# Event Notification of Data Availability in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

What will be the best approach towards implementing a notification system for Hadoop for data availability such that whenever new data comes its creates a notification which can be utilized by job control framework to start their job which depends on that data. Here the main concern is as soon as the data becomes available the job should get triggered instead job polling on NameNode for availability of data?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use a producer/consumer model that can interact with each other using a queue like for example Amazon SQS.

The producer will maintain a list of watched directories, and do `hadoop fs -test -e /path/to/watched/dir` every x seconds (where x should be a parameter), and if the command returns 0 with `$?` then you can send a message to the queue. The content of the message could be just the name of the directory that just appeared, or you could add some metadata and send it as a JSON object for example with additional fields.

On the other side the consumer will listen to the queue every y seconds (where y should be a parameter), and as soon as there is new data you can start your job on this directory.

Comment: thnx for your suggestion but what I am looking at is instead of polling every y second can it be done in a event driven manner where as soons as new data get created its meta will get updated in NameNode and NameNode fires an event and job control framework say Oozie will get notified about data availability and start its workflow.

Comment: There is no feature in HDFS for that that I know of, but you could also maybe constantly look at the logs to see when new files are being written and build something around that.

Comment: I was exactly looking for possibility to build something for that. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Here is the documentation from [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a1._Coordinator_Overview) for the same.

Comment: @bril Did you find any solution for this? Even I'm looking for a solution for the same question.

Comment: @NiranjanSubramanian: Yeah i did it using pub-sub messaging system. Evaluated on both ActiveMQ and LinkedIn Azakban. Refer to our work here: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-03107-1_60