# How to know that a new data is been added to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am implementing a Notification system based on publish subscribe model to notify about the availability of data as it arrives/loaded to HDFS. I did n't find a ways where to look for this. Is there any HDFS API which can be used to do this or what method should I use to get information of new data written to HDFS? I am using Hadoop v2.0.2 and I don't want to use HCatalog, I want to implement my own tool to do this.

Comment: checkout Apache Flume. Not exactly what you are looking, but might be of help.

Comment: I want to know which java package/classes in HDFS should I look for this to add this feature. As i know when client write data to HDFS, after completion of writing data it updates the namenode to indicate the file is now complete. I basically want to add my code after Namenode receives completion update.

Comment: look at the following 2 answers and I too believe that there isn'y anything available as of now with HDFS SDK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436748/event-notification-of-data-availability-in-hdfs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436748/event-notification-of-data-availability-in-hdfs

Comment: So, I assume the answers and discussions from Quora [1] were not sufficient? Several people incl. myself told you already that HDFS doesn't do it ATM and offered alternatives. Sigh.

[1] http://www.quora.com/Apache-Hadoop/What-are-the-ways-I-can-know-that-a-new-data-is-been-added-to-HDFS

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `Oozie Coordinator`.

`HDFS` is a file system, so something must be built on top of HDFS to check for file availability. `HBase` has coprocessor which are triggered procedures . But it is only available for HBase tables. So it cannot be used for detecting data availabilty in HDFS.

[Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) is a workflow scheduler system to manage Hadoop jobs. [Oozie Coordinator](https://github.com/yahoo/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases) jobs are recurrent Oozie Workflow jobs triggered by time (frequency) and data availabilty. Also you can execute other programs from it :

> Oozie is integrated with the rest of the Hadoop stack supporting
> several types of Hadoop jobs out of the box (such as Java map-reduce,
> Streaming map-reduce, Pig, Hive, Sqoop and Distcp) as well as system
> specific jobs (such as Java programs and shell scripts).

So you can use the file availability trigger for  your notification system too.

Answer (score 1):

If you use HDFS you might want to check out HBase as it has the functionality you want.  In HBase, you can create a pre-put (or post-put) coprocessor essentially acting equivilant to a MySQL Trigger- running a bit of code for every time data is written to a table.

If HBase doesn't suit your use case and you must use HDFS, AFAIK there aren't similar triggers.  You can try wrapping the HDFS API with your own code to perform the notification whenever data is written to your file system under the appropriate circumstances.  Alternatively, you can poll HDFS for changes (which sounds like an ugly alternative)...

Hope that helps

Comment: could you plz tell me where can I get enough information about HDFS API?

Comment: here is a javadoc for the hadoop java api: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/index.html.   Here is a simple tutorial for using the java api: http://linuxjunkies.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/a-hdfsclient-for-hadoop-using-the-native-java-api-a-tutorial/