# How to implement Apache storm to monitor HDFS directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-storm

I have a HDFS directory where files will be copied continuously (streaming) from many sources.

How to build a topology for monitoring the HDFS directory, i.e that whenever a new file is created in that directory it should be processed.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to monitor HDFS file/directory changes.

Take a look this question, which points to existing support in Oozie and HBase:
[How to know that a new data is been added to HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934079/how-to-know-that-a-new-data-is-been-added-to-hdfs)
You can send items into your topology for processing when new files are detected by these tools.

Or you can write your own custom logic in storm, listing and checking if new files are added in HDFS periodically. Check out tick tuples support in Storm.